# What causes Nautilus to restart whenever I kill it?

Tags: command-line, nautilus, process, session

In htop, I kill Nautilus, and within one second, it's back, with a new PID!

The restarted Nautilus shows in the Processes list, but has no GUI until I manually launch Nautilus...  I've heard mention of Nautilus works in lockstep with the desktop... maybe that is the reason(?).

Is there some sort of "watchdog" program keeping an eye on some distro-critical programs?  Monitoring Nautilus doesn't seem like a Linux kernel issue, so I just wonder what is happening here?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Gnome uses a *Session Manager* (`gnome-session`) to keep track of what it needs to do. It is responsible for bringing up the whole session, all subprocesses, restoring state and saving it when you log out.

> GNOME provides tools to allow your application to run smoothly from session to session. Users can log out with running applications and have those applications fully restored when they log back in.  – *from [the Gnome Documentation Library](http://library.gnome.org/devel/platform-overview/stable/session.html.en)*

Among other things, the session manager tries to keep it's instance of Nautilus running. Nautilus has to register with the session manager for that - which it does by default; naturally, there's a command-line option to disable it:

`nautilus --sm-disable`

You can kill a running Nautilus process for good by running:

`killall -9 nautilus`

Comment: Thanks Stefano.. You have given a good overview, and that's what I was after, but as is often the case, an explanation can bring up another question(s)...I'll mention one now: I ran `nautilus --sm-disable` (user and sudo). This may have disabled the connection to the session-manager, but the session-manager kept right on restarting nautilus (with "nautilus --sm-disable" showing in the process list)... So does this parameter only take effect if it is applied at session startup (vs. mid-session), and are there any serious ramifications when disabled? (I think auto-mounting would vanish, but...?

Comment: Well, `nautilus --sm-disable` in an [Undocumented Feature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undocumented_feature). So it's hard to say. But keep in mind that nautilus will restart *as soon as it's killed*, you'd have to start the first instance of it with this parameter. `killall nautilus && nautilus --sm-disable` won't work. The command doesn't disable the feature for the running instances of nautilus. You might try to combine mine and andrewsomething's answer. ;-)

Comment: use `killall -9 nautilus`.

Comment: `nautilus --sm-disable` doesn't work in Ubuntu 15.10 (`Unknown option --sm-disable`). Also there is no Gnome session.

Answer (score 11):

As others have mentioned, `gnome-session` respawns the `nautilus` process automatically. It also does so for `gnome-panel` and `gnome-wm` (which in turn starts the window manager configured by the user, usually `compiz` or `metacity`).

This behavior is customizable through the `desktop > gnome > session > required_components` gconf keys.

[image: required_components gconf keys]

Editing these value can be useful if you would like to, for instance, run with out the GNOME Panel and only use Docky or AWN.

Answer (score 6):

`gnome-session` is responsible for respawning nautilus. As its parent in the process tree, there is no other process that could respawn it.

`ps -eaH` shows you the hierarchical process tree excerpted here:

```
    1 ?        00:00:00 init
 1113 ?        00:00:00   gdm-binary
11391 ?        00:00:00     gdm-simple-slav
11396 tty8     00:00:13       Xorg
11465 ?        00:00:00       gdm-session-wor
11629 ?        00:00:00         gnome-session
11746 ?        00:00:02           nautilus
```

Comment: Thanks msw... That's quite an informative listing (-eaH).

Answer (score 5):

Chipaca & andrewsomething are both close...  :)

The `/desktop/gnome/session/required_components_list` key lists the "components" that should be monitored by `gnome-session`, and restarted automatically when they exit.  The default value for GNOME 2 is something like `[windowmanager,panel,filemanager]`.

If you want to prevent nautilus (or whatever "filemanager component" you have configured) from getting (re)started by this mechanism, you can change the value to `[windowmanager,panel]`.  (You can still have it start during login by adding it to the list of session start-up programs of course, but it won't get restarted automatically anymore.)

What application (with what commandline parameters) gets started for each component is defined under `/desktop/gnome/session/required_components` in a key with the name of the component.  It is possible that more components are listed here than are used in the `/desktop/gnome/session/required_components_list` key.

Now, in case of nautilus, by default when it is not running yet it starts in the background, and if the `/apps/nautilus/preferences/show_desktop` key is set it also shows the Desktop.  It is also possible to tell nautilus to behave differently with commandline parameters.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Nautilus is being restarted because you have it drawing the desktop. Enter

```
gconftool-2 --type bool --set /apps/nautilus/preferences/show_desktop False
```

in a terminal for it to stop doing that, and it then shouldn't come back after killing.

Comment: The `show_desktop = False` option does **not** prevent Nautilus from restarting... so I think Nautilus must be doing more behind the scenes than just that...  By the way, I **like** this option, as I don't keep anything on the desktop, and it is annoying when Screenshot saves its images there (it doesn't seem to have any way to change this).... Also just noticed another option I **really like**: `show_advanced_permissions True` ... Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

## in total do:

```
gconftool-2 -s -t bool /desktop/gnome/background/draw_background false
gconftool-2 -s -t bool /apps/nautilus/preferences/show_desktop false
```

and

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop
```

## change to:

X-GNOME-AutoRestart=false

(found it at:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=119254 )

## thats all...